# Digital Logic Question involving Muxs

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

I'm having trouble understanding the solution to this digital circuit problem involving muxes. Could anybody explain how they got to this answer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is an exercise in converting logic gates to multiplexers, which are essentially used as look-up tables.

Let's first redraw the leftmost of the four identical parts of the circuit, which are the basic building blocks:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2titW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now we have to convert this logic circuit into an equivalent circuit with the least amount of 2-to-1 multiplexers possible. Multiplexers can be used as look-up tables and can implement every existing logic gate, provided they have enough input pins.

- Can we do it with one? Obviously not, we don't have enough inputs.
- Can we do it with two? Yes! Because now we can replace both gates (NOT, AND and XOR) with a MUX each that has the same truth table.

An equivalent MUX circuit for the NOT, AND gate would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbbEur.png)</sup>

An equivalent MUX circuit for the XOR gate would be:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0YC0.png)</sup>

The exercise text states that the inputs are also available in complement (inverted) form. So I used one of these complement signals as a_inv.

If we now assemble the subcircuits we get the equivalent of the original circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsPyNX.png)</sup>

If you compare the truth table of the original circuit with this multiplexer equivalent you will see that they are equal.
In text form, my circuit equals the first exercise solution: mux(a, a', mux(c, '0', b))

You should now be able to derive from that the second solution and also the solution for output x in the original exercise diagram.

Comment: Fantastic answer sir, thank you for taking the time to respond.