# The minimum size of the multiplexer needed?

Tags: multiplexer

Suppose only one multiplexer and one inverter are allowed to be used to implement any Boolean function of n variables. What is the minimum size of the multiplexer needed?

Answer is: 2<sup>n−1</sup> to 1

Any help provided to understand this question is appreciated.

Comment: Related to your question, maybe it helps: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383660/digital-logic-question-involving-muxs/383721#383721

Answer (score 0):

circuit input n goes to the inverter
circuit inputs 1 to n-1 go the multiplexer address lines

mux data inputs are wired to 1,0,n or not(n) as required to produce your function on the output.

Comment: what would happen if we are not given with NOT GATE/INVERTER?

Comment: then you would not have `not n` as a choice for mux inputs so you'd only be able to fully handle functions of n-1 bits.